# Make A List of Only the Most Specific Codes

Tags: python, tree

I have a list of codes that are ordered in a nested structure. For example, here are the first 20:

`codes`
8
8.5
**8.51
8.52**
**8.6
8.7**
**10**
31
**31.1**
38
**38.1
38.2
38.3**
41
41.1
**41.11
41.12**
41.2
**41.21**
**41.4**

The more decimal points, the more specific the code. I need to find a way to make a list of only the most specific codes which I have highlighted in bold. If you imagine these numbers as a tree where each decimal rounding level corresponds to a node level in the tree, I need to get all the leaves.

For example, 8.51 is more specific than 8.5 which is more specific than 8. 8.6 is also a leaf because it is more specific than 8 and there are no child nodes coming from it.

Here's a diagram of the proposed tree structure given these 20 codes:
[image]

The tree structure is perfectly defined by the input array `codes`, because if a number `A.abc` exists in the array, then `A.ab`, `A.a`, and `A` must exist in the array as well. The array is conveniently sorted ascendingly.

I'd like an algorithm that finds these leaves and collects them in a list/vector. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two questions: 1) is the array always sorted, and 2) are all used roundings corresponding to a leaf present, or can some be missing? E.g.: Do you always have `8, 8.4, 8.42, 8.423` etc or can you have `8, 8.4, 8.423` (missing rounding to hundredths).

Comment: @GeorgyKopshteyn I've tried comparing the number of characters in a number to those in the numbers directly before and after (Ex: if same #char as previous, add to list). This works but I'm having trouble at the points where the parent node changed (ex: when you go from 8.7 to 10). I'm not sure how to get around this. I'm thinking I may need to split into several lists (Ex: list 1 is 8 and all its children, list 2 is 10 and all its children) then operate on each list separately.

Comment: Do you try to make some graph of relations? I don't see any logic of bold numbers. Why 10 is bold?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I only have to do this once, but yes my list is sorted. And we have the former situation. There are no missing "levels."

Comment: @Spencer You could turn all list entries into strings, split them at ".", put the two parts of those splits into tupel (int-part, decimal-part), make a list of the tupels obtained this way, iterate over this new list and compare the length of the tupels' decimal-part entry for those tupels who have the the same int-part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
codes = [8.0, 8.5, 8.51, 8.52, 8.6, 8.7, 10, 31, 31.1, 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 41, 41.1, 41.11, 41.12, 41.2, 41.21, 41.4]

def to_str(num):
    s = str(num)
    if ".0" in s and s.endswith("0"):
        return str(int(num))
    else:
        return s

def is_prefix_of(a, b):
    return to_str(b).startswith(to_str(a))
    
def get_specifics(A):
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        if not is_prefix_of(A[i], A[i+1]):
            ret.append(A[i])
    ret.append(A[-1])
    return ret
    
print(get_specifics(codes))

# [8.51, 8.52, 8.6, 8.7, 10, 31.1, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 41.11, 41.12, 41.21, 41.4]
```

I assumed that the answers to 1) is the array always sorted, and 2) are all used roundings corresponding to a leaf present, or can some be missing? E.g.: Do you always have `8, 8.4, 8.42, 8.423` etc or can you have `8, 8.4, 8.423` (missing rounding to hundredths) are both YES.

These have now been confirmed to be true by OP.

EDIT: converting `float` integers to `ints` correctly.

Comment: For some reason, when I import my csv file to python with pandas, it gives a trailing zero to integer codes (Ex: 8 -> 8.0) which causes the code to not work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Spencer I've updated my code to handle that case. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes and I've accepted your answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote as well if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension by counting the number of decimals and adding values which have decimals larger than 2. Try this:

```py
lst = [8, 8.5, 8.51, 8.52, 8.6, 8.7, 10, 31, 31.1, 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 41, 41.1, 41.11, 41.12, 41.2, 41.21, 41.4]
lst2 = [i for i in lst if str(i)[::-1].find('.')>=2]
```

`str(i)[::-1].find('.')` just gets the number of decimals after the point. You can then append values to the list if the number of decimals `>=2`, or whatever you please

Comment: How does that return the most specific numbers?

Comment: It returns the numbers with more than 2 decimal places

Comment: If that's not what you mean by specific, then please explain what you mean

Comment: Well, reading the question body thorougly might help. Basically, the `specific` numbers according to OP are those which are not a prefix to any other number in the list.

Comment: And I did
But you aren't explaining it